# Android Saving files with extensions causes the file to become a directory

Tags: java, android

When I try to save a file using:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "SomeFile.someExtension");
```

causes the file to become a directory.
What causes this? How can this be fixed \ bypassed?
Note that this does not happen when omitting the extension, i.e using

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "SomeFile");
```

Works normally, creating a file.

Side-note: I did check in google, and didn't find anyone asking this specific issue, rather asking how to check the extensions of a file.

Comment: creating a file object will not create a directory. Show us your further way what do you do with that file...maybe there is the issue...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs This is literally the way I am doing this, feel free to test this out yourself, I am running Android Studio 2.3, with Android, min sdk is 19, compiled version is 25.

Comment: @Nithinlal Lol. He said directory is getting created so obviously he has given permission.

Comment: @Nithinlal Besides the fact that I am trying to save this to internal storage (which doesn't require permissions), I have also added permission for external storage as well, just to be sure (and runtime-permission requests for anything above Marshmallow).

Comment: @Alon.G. Try - 
     
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "/SomeFile.someExtension");

Comment: @AmbujKathotiya Doesn't work.

Comment: Only calling the File constructor doesn't create an object on disk ... it just creates a File instance ... you have to call createNewFile() or something like that to really create a file ... there has to be something else in your code creating a directory ...

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn Doesn't work either. Like I said, the code I wrote is the code I wrote in the project.

Comment: there must be something like `outputstream.write()` or for example `file.createNewFile()`

Comment: and by the way `getFilesDir()` gives you the path of your app-internal file directory, this could be created automatically...